# JQuery FileReader onload not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a multiple file uploading. When I upload the images and binding to the model as follows not firing the FileReader onload function. It skip and fire remain

Here is my code

```
imageSelect: function (e) {
            var dataModel = bindViewModel.selected.attachments;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                var uploadImg = new Image();
                uploadImg.onload = function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
                        if (e.files[i].size < 1048576) {
                            var attachmentName = e.files[i].name;
                            var attachment = { id: i, citationId: bindViewModel.selected.id, attachmentName: attachmentName, attachmentUrl: reader.result };
                            dataModel.push(attachment);
                            if (dataModel[0].attachmentName == "" && dataModel[0].attachmentUrl == "") {
                                dataModel.splice($.inArray(dataModel[0], dataModel), 1);
                            }
                            uploadImg.src = reader.result;
                            reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[i].rawFile);
                        }
                        else {
                            app.ShowNotifications("Error", 'The ' + e.files[i].name + ' size greater than 1MB. \r\n Maximum allowed file size is 1MB.', "error");
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
        }
```

Any one can have to help me?

Comment: You've to load something with the newly-created reader --> pull `reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[i].rawFile);` out of the handler. The logic for the argument needs some rethink, though.

Comment: Where do you read the file? You initialize it, where do you tell it to run?

Comment: I read it for get the full url by reader.Result

Comment: The onload is fired after reading, and you read in the onload handler, which will be never fired without reading first ,,, Just creating a reader object doesn't trigger its onload event.